# Closing a .NET form causes the parent to minimize

Tags: c#, winforms, showdialog

I have an issue where the parent form will minimize to the task tray (but I don't think it is losing focus because the next form that shows, the Studio IDE, has focus) when I close a dialog/form that was shown by calling `ShowDialog(owner)`.

The weird thing is that this doesn't happen every time. I don't see how the owner/parent parameter is getting cleared so I don't know why the parent would go away.

Comment: Can you post some code? I can't recreate this scenario no matter what I try.

Answer (score 4):

I can reproduce it every time.

The bug is not in WinForms, but in the windows API (I can just as easily reproduce it with C code).

Avoid triple-nested dialogs, that seems to be the primary trigger.

You can also refocus the correct form in OnClose.

Comment: Also avoid showing MDI parent dialogs from MDI children forms. And you can't refocus, because only the focused application can focus forms. If you try to focus before the close, there's a dialog open so you can't. If you try after the close, you've lost focus yourself and you'll fail silently.

Comment: Funny, my test said that in WM_CLOSE, set focus to another form in the same app always worked. The anti-focus is asynchronous and if you call DestroyWindow() immediately afterwords it gets eaten.

Comment: It does seem to be "triple nested dialogs" that causes this. Overriding `OnClosed` with `Owner?.Activate();` is an easy fix.

Answer (score 1):

Set the focus to the Mdiparent of the form just before calling the Close().
Works for me...

Comment: In my case I was not in a MDI form but also setting the focus in the owner window just after the call to `ShowDialog` did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

in MdiParent...... all the child forms are automatically loaded with
{Maximize}{Minimize}{CLose} buttons...

You just need to use those buttons,,,,,, like in normal window.....

the forms will get rminimized and still will be shown in MdiParent....

Ref: http://www.itpian.com/Coding/6412-How-to-minimize-Form-which-is-shown-in-parent-Form.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this code, I have same problem and finally find this solution

```
ChildForm childForm = new ChildForm();
childForm.Show(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you cracked this but it might be the way you are handling the events in the dialog.  Make sure you have the dialog forms AcceptButton and CancelButton properties set and then just return the result in their click event handlers.

If you have any code that hides the dialog you will experience your problem.